# Talend Truncate Table does not empty table

Tags: sql-server, talend

I use TOS to transfer a SQL Server table to another SQL Server. That works more or less. But I have one issue with truncating the table. In the properties for the output table I define "Truncate Table" for the table action and "Insert" for the data action. At the second run I get a lot of duplicate key errors. If I run the "TRUNCATE TABLE" manually in the SQL Server Management Studio, the job works fine.

Are there any known issues with truncate table? Talens Version is 5.3.2

Thanks in advance

Comment: Presumably Talend connects via a linked server, and direct DDL commands are not permitted on remote connections. Are you able to change the specific query text that the application runs?

Comment: to keep things simple - you can try to give truncate table tablename command before the insert flow..via tMssqlRow component..so remove truncate from your output component and use tmssqlrow component

Comment: No, the Connection is via JDBC in this case. And changing the query is not possible as far as I know. i can see the Statement but it's generated every time you save the Job.

Comment: Hi garpitmzn, thx for Suggestion. But I get the tMssqlRow not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mimicked the scenario and it works fine in Talend Platform for data Management version 5.6.1.  I cannot test it on the TOS, but perhaps you can upgrade to the newest TOS version and try again.  To be thorough I tried it using separate connection components and  built-in connections.  The only difference is that  using separate connection object requires a commit object.

The workaround I recommend is this:

- create a proc to truncate your table and call it from a tMSSqlSP component
- connect this to your original subjob which transfers the data between the two tables using an OnSubJobOK flow.
- In your tMSSqlOutput component (which performs the truncate/insert) in for Action on Table use Default (so it will not truncate the table)
- for Action on data use Insert

I tried this method and it works.  This workaround will save you the time and frustration of dealing with the TOS issue.